# Async request with status = 0

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have some issues with async requests. My website and api are on different ports, Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is set on API side correctly (because synchronious requests work just fine).

The following code always returns 'ERR'. I

```
function load() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://domain:8801/api/', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status != 200) {
            alert( "ERR" + " Status: " + xhr.statusText + " Response: "+xhr.responseText ); //always ERR in browser
        }
        else {
            alert( "SUCCESS" );
        }
    }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: So... your service is always returning an error?  I don't know what help you expect us to be able to give with this code.  It's a backend problem

Comment: so what exactly does `xhr.status`contain? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Response_codes

Comment: don't dump out a fixed error message. that's totally useless. `alert(xhr.statusText)` will TELL you what the problem is. or at least spit out `xhr.status` itself so you can see the http code at least.

Comment: Status 0 usually indicates a network or security error. The console should give you a more complete error message.

Comment: @Codeman but with sync requests everything works fine, so its not a backend problem

Comment: @MarcB statusText and responseText are both empty. status is 0

Comment: what happens if you change to `xhr.onload` instead of `xhr.onreadystatechange`?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss nothing appears in the box. just nothing. on the server side I see request with 400 response code

Comment: 400 Bad Request This response means that server could not understand the request due to invalid syntax.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss but how is it possible that with synchronous request everything works just fine? The only change is from 'false' to 'true' in open method

Comment: Note that `xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")`; should come before the open...not even sure you need that here.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss yeah. its irrelevant here. not the point still

Answer (score 0):

Set a listener for the returned async

```
function reqListener() {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}

function load() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
  xhr.open('GET', 'http://domain:8801/api/');
  xhr.send();
}
```

Not putting in true/false makes it async by default

SO this is all wrong and the "submit" button is the issue - and the async operates differently - the sync waits for response, THEN submits while the async does not and it never returns prior to the submit action

Comment: after first button push nothing appears. after second I see backend response (what I expect to see, actually)

Comment: likely something to do with "button push" whatever that is - show the code for that...

Comment: As simple as it could be    <input type="submit" onclick="load()" >

Comment: NOT so simple = change the type to NOT be submit OR it will attempt that by default  Might try `<button type="button"  onclick="load()">click</buttonn>` I would add an event listener in code instead of embedding it though

Comment: okay, the button type works fine, thank you! but what shall i do with forms and submitting them?

Comment: Don't try to use/do both from the same input? i.e. use ajax or don't

Comment: well, in that case: i have a textbox and a button (which should submit the form). how to activate 'submitting' after pushing 'Enter' key on keyboard while in textbox? onsubmit in the form doesn't work - status = 0